# Java 8 inside jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, java-8, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I am using version 2.445 of Jenkins by default it comes with java version 17, but I have a job that requires java version 8, can anyone help me how to do that. I have tried various plugins to that

Manage Jenkins -> Tools -> jdk installations, but on running the job i was getting the below error

```
Installing JDK jdk-8-oth-JPR
Downloading JDK from https://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/8-b132/jdk-8-linux-x64.tar.gz
Downloading 5307 bytes
Installing /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh
[Java_8] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh -noregister
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 1: cannot open html: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 2: cannot open head: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 3: cannot open title: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 4: cannot open META: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 5: cannot open link: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 6: cannot open link: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 7: 
: not found
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 8: cannot open body: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 9: cannot open div: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 10: cannot open table: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 11: cannot open tr: No such file
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/Java_8/jdk.sh: 12: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Below is my pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools{
        jdk 'Java 8'
    }

    stages {
            stage('example'){
                steps{
                sh 'env | grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME'
                sh 'java --version'
                }
            }
       
        }
}
```

Comment: No one should be running JDK 8 anymore.  LTS version is 21.  You should be thinking about upgrading, not downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend to decouple your build environment from the Jenkins and/or agent setup using containers. Using this approach, you will be able to simply select the desired image and its version to fully control your build environment independently for each project without reconfiguring your Jenkins instance and agents each time you need an update:

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            registryUrl: 'docker registry of your choice goes here'
            image: 'jdk image of your choice goes here'
        }
    }

    stages {
        stage('example') {
            steps {
                sh 'env | grep -e PATH -e JAVA_HOME'
                sh 'java --version'
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Read Jenkins [documentation on using Docker in pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) for details.

Also note https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/505 when you select your build image. If you're running this within your organization, you probably already have some approved internal registry and images that you should use.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jenkins to use the Java version you want. Go to `Jenkins > Jenkins Administration > Plugin Configuration` or similar and install the Java plugin that let you to choose the Java version you want.